# Add user to SharePoint group using rest api not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2013, sharepoint-designer, jquery, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to add a user to the SharePoint group from the REST API in SharePoint 2013.

It says successfully added but never adds the user

```
    function addUserToGroup(userloginname) {
    var addUserToGroupEndpoint =  "https://mysite/_api/web/sitegroups(12061)/users";

    var payload = JSON.stringify({
        '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' },
        'LoginName': ''+userloginname+''
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: addUserToGroupEndpoint,
        type: "POST",
        data: payload,
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("User Added to Group successfully!");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error + "Inform admins");
        }
    });
}
```

I am running out of ideas, if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the working SharePoint REST API example to add user to SharePoint group:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="addUserToGroup()"> Add User To Group </button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function addUserToGroup() {
        var addUserToGroupEndpoint = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/sitegroups(38)/users";

        var payload = JSON.stringify({
            '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.User' },
            'LoginName': 'i:0#.f|membership|meganb@contoso.com'
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: addUserToGroupEndpoint,
            type: "POST",
            data: payload,
            headers: {
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("User Added to Group successfully!");
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Make sure you are using correct login name of user and the ID of your SharePoint group.

I just tried this and it is working fine for me:

[image]

Comment: i am getting 404 error for this line "https://mysite/_api/web/sitegroups(12061)/users i am the site collection admin for the site.

Comment: it worked for a while then all of a sudden I get this failed to load resource error on the button click, but when I click on the link then i am able to see the group details

Comment: Are you using correct group ID, can you confirm it once?

Comment: yeah, I am I can browse in individually mysite/_api/web/sitegroups(12061)/users but when my function is calling it on the button click it says 404.

Comment: can you add the updated code you are using currently to your question by editing original question? Is there any detailed error message with 404 code?

Comment: added the updated code, it errors out failed to load resource, the server responded with status of 404